# Unable to close/edit excel sheet after GUI call in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button in my GUI which calls this procedure:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPersonalFilter_Click()
    Unload GUI
    Dim myPath As String

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    myPath = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1)
    If Dir(myPath & "\filterPartsList.xlsx") = "" Then
        FileCopy "Z:\Dokumentstyring\Templates\filterPartsList.xlsx", myPath & "\filterPartsList.xlsx"
    End If
    Set Wb = HelpFunctions.GetWorkbook(myPath & "\filterPartsList.xlsx")
    Wb.Activate
    Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
    Set Wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I click the button(from a.xlsx) it opens up a new workbook(b.xlsx, all as it should), but if I then decide that the b.xlsx is just fine and I would like to **close b.xlsx (or edit)**, then I am only allowed to do so **if I first jump back to a.xlsx, click on any cell there and then jump back to the b.xlsx**

Below is the helper function:

```
Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbReturn As Workbook

    sFile = Dir(sFullName)

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)

        If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
            Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn

End Function
```

Not a big issue but would be nice to figure out where the problem might be. All macros are stored in personal.xlsb

Comment: Programmatically speaking, `Dim Wb As Workbook` declare this variable as local to the procedure, so you can't really call it later, you could use a Public variable to keep the reference at hand and use it later. For the manual manipulation, it's a bit strange...

Comment: I see no wb.close in your code.

Comment: I don't want to close it in vba, only manually if all is Ok withb.xlsx.

Comment: It might be some issue with personal.xlsb, seems pretty unstable, sometimes it loads correctly sometimes not.

Comment: Try adding: `Me.Hide` as the first line of the routine.

Comment: Try moving `Unload GUI` to the last line of the sub.